# Is there a way to update the Google Script App on a Google Site to keep several user's input in sync without each clicking a refresh button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have check boxes in the UI of a Google Script App on a Google Site page and would like the check boxes on the other users viewing the same Google Site Page to also become checked when one of the users click on it.  Is this possible?

Comment: You're talking about using a "Shared" state in a UiApp?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. At least, not in the way we'd like.

There's some "nasty" workarounds that you may apply. e.g. responding to mouse movements inside your App. But this has the problem of exaggerated events generated when the user moves the mouse, and no events at all if he moves out of your script windows or if he's more of a keyboard user.

Also, you could add multiple handlers to the same button, where each handler has a different sleep time, therefore updating the GUI later. But this has a limitation of the maximum time a script execution may last (5 minutes). On the "last" handler you could inform your user that he has to click again to start another 5 minutes round of updates.

Either way, both workarounds consist in checking if the values changed somewhere (e.g. a spreadsheet cell) manually. It's not "event-triggered" and therefore will be very "computer intensive", which will most likely make your script hit one or more of the various [quotas](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard).

If this is important, you should open an "Enhancement request" in Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and explain your usage.